# Conditional, is IF optional?

Tags: conditionals

I’ve just read this sentence:

> Machines might decide the world would be better without humans.

Why there is not an IF?

> Machines might decide IF the world…

Comment: There's no *if* because "the world would be better without humans" is the Complement of the verb *decide*, not a conditional Adjunct. In other words the sentence means exactly the same as "Machines might decide **that** the world would be better without humans".

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to EL&U!

Answer (score 1):

The statement with an IF has a different meaning. Without the IF it means that machines might make a particular decision - that the world would be better without humans. The statement with the IF means that machines might make a decision on the subject, but it does not suggest what that decision might be.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a conditional, it's another thing called a subjunctive. The missing optional word is not "if", it's "that".

> Machines might decide that the world would be better without humans

This would have the same meaning; in this case we are imagining that machines are imagining a world without humans that is a better world.

> Machines might decide if the world would be better without humans

This is a conditional. It has a different meaning; in this case, the machines could decide that the imagined world is NOT better without humans, or it could decide that the imagined world IS better without humans, and either way, the machines decides IF the world would be better without humans.

Edit: There actually is a conditional in your sentence, it's just not where you said it was. "The world would be better without humans" is the conditional part. "Would" makes it conditional, there is no need for "if", but it could be written "The world would be better if there were no humans in it".

Comment: There is nothing "subjunctive" here.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry if I've made a mistake. What mood is it if not the subjunctive mood? Perhaps the definition of "would" as "A modal verb, the subjunctive of will; usually followed by a bare infinitive" is incorrect on wiktionary as well? Thanks

Comment: This *would* is the past of *will*, as in *They thought it would be better*, perhaps the sense the OED says is used this way: “22. a. Expressing past prediction of a future event in a subordinate clause or in virtual reported speech or thought. Cf. sense 14. Sometimes expressing a serious warning of the certainty of a future event. Occasionally in *would have* followed by the past participle, indicating an action or process already completed in the future, but (since the construction is mostly used when the outcome is not as expected) this use merges with the hypothetical use (sense 27).“

Comment: So you think "The world would be better without humans" is a statement about the past? Could you say, for example, "The world would be  better without humans 100 years ago"? If so, what does that sentence mean?

Comment: "This is a conditional" <-- It isn't! the clause *if the world would be better without humans* is an interrogative clause, not a conditional one! It means the same as "whether the world would be better without humans."

Comment: It is a statement _in_ the past, not about the past. Don't confuse the time of the inflection with the time being referenced. "They **think** the world **is** going to be better without humans" in the present tense (*think, is*) becomes "They **thought** the world **was** going to be better without humans" in the past tense (*thought, was*).  I've used the *is going to* periphrasis of *will* so that I can mark the tense normally, without modals. But it's a reference to a time in the future either way. This is all past tense: "They **thought** the world **would** be better without humans."

Comment: So again, for "Machines might decide the world would be better without humans", is "might decide" also in the past tense? And if I said "Machines might decide the world would be better without humans 100 years ago", would the machines be 100 years ago or would the world be 100 years ago? Who or what is in the past?